# Using str_replace() with a string imported from an SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Im trying to keep formatting when text is sent to a SQL database and when it is returned.
The scenario is Customer sends a support request. I need it so that all formatting used in the description, the only text entry option, is kept and then displayed by User Support exactly as the Customer sent it.

```
<tr>
  <td width="30%" valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;"><div align="left">Summary :<font color="#CC3300"></font></div></td>
  <td width="70%" valign="top"><?php echo stripslashes($rec['summary'])?></td>
</tr>
```

The text sent by the Customer is saved in the database under summary.
I have when the Customer sends the request that the text they send goes through

```
nl2br
```

and in the database, PHPMyAdmin, it displays with the correct formatting.
How would I be able to keep the line breaks sent when they are shown to user support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't `nl2br` the input when you put it in the database, you should `nl2br` it when you display it when you need the `<br>` in the code.

That way, you still have the original, and can still add `<br>` later.

Always keep the stored data clean of any formatting when you can

Comment: `$rec['summary']` contains the message? Around it! Also, why stripslashes?

Comment: this also saves you from the problem of suddenly having too many `<br>`s in your output!